# Summarizing one-hour windows of timestamped data in R using slide_dfr

Tags: r

Question:

I have a data frame in R that contains timestamps (time)(though the date is irrelevant in this case, only time matters) and a corresponding value (E). The timestamps represent specific instances during a day, and the value represents the number of entries at each of those instances.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
time <- c("1899-12-31 08:07:18 UTC", "1899-12-31 08:17:18 UTC", 
      "1899-12-31 08:27:33 UTC", "1899-12-31 08:57:28 UTC", 
      "1899-12-31 09:07:18 UTC", "1899-12-31 09:17:18 UTC", 
      "1899-12-31 09:27:19 UTC", "1899-12-31 09:57:52 UTC", 
      "1899-12-31 10:07:18 UTC", "1899-12-31 10:17:42 UTC", 
      "1899-12-31 11:37:42 UTC", "1899-12-31 11:47:35 UTC",
      "1899-12-31 11:57:20 UTC", "1899-12-31 12:07:37 UTC",
      "1899-12-31 12:17:18 UTC", "1899-12-31 12:27:18 UTC",
      "1899-12-31 13:37:44 UTC", "1899-12-31 13:47:29 UTC",
      "1899-12-31 13:57:08 UTC", "1899-12-31 14:07:00 UTC",
      "1899-12-31 14:57:27 UTC", "1899-12-31 15:07:18 UTC",
      "1899-12-31 15:37:15 UTC", "1899-12-31 15:47:18 UTC")

E <- c(1, 5, 3, 8, 7, 2, 7, 1, 3, 8, 4, 9,
       10, 7, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 11, 5, 2, 3, 2)

df <- tibble(time, E) %>% mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time))
```

My goal is to find the one-hour time window with the maximum sum of E, and I want the start and end time of this window.

I've tried using the slide_dfr function from the slider package, as follows:

```
library(slider)

# Define the summarizing function
calculate_one_hour <- function(data) {
  print(paste("Number of rows in window:", nrow(data)))
  data <- data %>% drop_na(E, time)
  tibble(
    start_time = min(data$time, na.rm = TRUE),
    end_time = max(data$time, na.rm = TRUE),
    sum = sum(data$E, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
} 

# Calculate the minimum and maximum times in seconds past midnight
min_time <- min(hour(df$time) * 3600 + minute(df$time) * 60 + second(df$time))
max_time <- max(hour(df$time) * 3600 + minute(df$time) * 60 + second(df$time))

# Generate all seconds between min_time and max_time
all_seconds <- tibble(
  seconds = seq(from = min_time, to = max_time, by = 1)
)

# Merge this with the original data
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(seconds = as.integer(hour(time) * 3600 + minute(time) * 60 + second(time))) %>%
  right_join(all_seconds, by = "seconds")

# Slide the summarizing function over the data
result <- df %>% 
  arrange(seconds) %>%
  slide_dfr(.x = ., .i = all_seconds, .f = ~ calculate_one_hour(.x), .width = 3600)

# Find the hour with the maximum sum
max_hour <- result %>% 
  filter(sum == max(sum))
```

However, the output result data frame has the same number of rows as my original data frame, and the start_time, end_time, and sum values are identical in all rows. I expect result to contain different one-hour windows, with corresponding sums of E.

I've also checked that calculate_one_hour function processes each window correctly by printing the number of rows in each window, and it turns out to be 1, which is not what I expected.

Could anyone help me understand why slide_dfr isn't working as expected here, and suggest how to modify my code to achieve the desired results? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using the *runner* library.

```
library(runner)
# Define a function to calculate the rolling sum over a one-hour window
calculate_one_hour <- function(data) {
  data %>%
    mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time),
           sum_E = map_dbl(seq_along(time), 
                           ~ data %>% 
                             filter(between(time, time[.x], time[.x] + hours(1))) %>% 
                             summarise(sum = sum(E, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                             pull(sum)),
           end_time = map_dbl(seq_along(time), 
                              ~ data %>% 
                                filter(between(time, time[.x], time[.x] + hours(1))) %>% 
                                summarise(end_time = max(time)) %>% 
                                pull(end_time))
    )
}

df <- calculate_one_hour(df) %>% 
  mutate(end_time = as.POSIXct(end_time, origin = "1970-01-01"))


# Find the hour with the maximum sum
max_hour <- df %>% select(-E) %>% 
  filter(sum_E == max(sum_E))
```

In this code, calculate_one_hour is a function that calculates the rolling sum of column E over a one-hour window for each timestamp in the data frame. It creates two new columns: sum_E which represents the sum of column E over a one-hour window, and end_time which represents the end time of the one-hour window.

The between function is used to filter rows that fall within a one-hour window.

Finally, the line df <- calculate_one_hour(df) %>% mutate(end_time = as.POSIXct(end_time, origin = "1970-01-01")) applies this function to the data frame and converts the end_time column to a date-time format.

I encourage others to contribute to this discussion. The more insights and approaches we share, the richer our understanding becomes. There may also be more efficient or alternative methods to achieve this same task in R. Let's continue to learn from each other!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to summarise by distinct and gapless moving one-hour time windows, i.e starting with 08:08:17 - 09:08:17 and shifting that by one hour until the end, you can use my package timeplyr.

```
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(timeplyr)
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(time = ymd_hms(time)) %>%
  time_summarise(time, sum = sum(E), time_by = "hour", 
                 include_interval = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(desc(sum))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  time                interval                                           sum
  <dttm>              <Interval>                                       <dbl>
1 1899-12-31 13:07:18 1899-12-31 13:07:18 UTC--1899-12-31 14:07:18 UTC    34
2 1899-12-31 11:07:18 1899-12-31 11:07:18 UTC--1899-12-31 12:07:18 UTC    23
3 1899-12-31 08:07:18 1899-12-31 08:07:18 UTC--1899-12-31 09:07:18 UTC    17
4 1899-12-31 09:07:18 1899-12-31 09:07:18 UTC--1899-12-31 10:07:18 UTC    17
5 1899-12-31 12:07:18 1899-12-31 12:07:18 UTC--1899-12-31 13:07:18 UTC    12
6 1899-12-31 10:07:18 1899-12-31 10:07:18 UTC--1899-12-31 11:07:18 UTC    11
7 1899-12-31 15:07:18 1899-12-31 15:07:18 UTC--1899-12-31 15:47:18 UTC     7
8 1899-12-31 14:07:18 1899-12-31 14:07:18 UTC--1899-12-31 15:07:18 UTC     5
```

With these types of moving windows, the largest sum is 34

between 1899-12-31 13:07:18 and 1899-12-31 14:07:18.